# electron does not connect to localhost

Tags: node.js, localhost, electron, atom-editor

I am using node js to connect local server (localhost), when I run the application in electron the queries get executed. But when it is deployed into an application .and when I install the setup file, node js code wont execute the queries. It doesn’t connect to local host. What is the solution for these??

Comment: what are you using to query? You can enable devtools in the production app and verify what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that localhost is accessible on the machine you are deploying the app.
I cant help much, uploading your code snippet might help in resolving your issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i got it resolved . i sin install mysql remotely to my client application